# Are there any free tier like F1 in DevOps Starter (Azure)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying out `DevOps Start` from Azure. Under `Location`, Are there any free tier like F1 in DevOps Starter (Azure)?

[image]

I tried `SouthEast Asia` but the Deployment failed with this error

> "This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try
> selecting different region or SKU."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the 'Additional settings' and you should able to select the F1 tier.

[image]

Comment: Looks like F1 only available at Window, not Linux.